# Azure block-blob storage uploading same file in succession fails

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I' m using Azure Block Blob Storage to keep my files. Here is my code to upload file.

I m calling the method twice as below for the same file in the same request;
The first call of the method saves the file as expected but the second call saves file as length of 0 so i cant display the image and no error occurs.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        UploadFile(file);
        UploadFile(file); 
        return View();
    }

      public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file){

        var credentials = new StorageCredentials("accountName", "key");

        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        var containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        };

        container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);

        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

        var azureFileUrl = string.Format("{0}", blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

        try
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);
        }

        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return azureFileUrl ;
    }
```

I just find the below solution which is strange like mine, but it does not help.

[Strange Sudden Error "The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987351/strange-sudden-error-the-number-of-bytes-to-be-written-is-greater-than-the-spec)

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: BTW, why are you calling this method twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the position of the stream back to the beginning. Put this line at the top of your UploadFile method.

```
file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, this solved my issue. Actually i m going to refactor this method to save different size of images, i need to save 2 version of the same file in the same post action so i will be calling it twice with different width&height parameters, anyways. What is the logic here about seek method? I m calling the method so I instantiate different instance of block blob etc. why i need to start from 0 again?

Comment: Yes, but the file pointer for your source file (the posted file) is at the end of the file after streaming it to the first blob. So, you have to move it back to the beginning if your are going to read it again.